# QLineEdit not release the focus when click in QGroupBox

Tags: qt, qlineedit, qt-signals, qgroupbox

```
    int main(int ac, char **av) 
    {
        QApplication app(ac, av);
        Dialog *dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog->show();
        return app.exec();
    }



namespace Ui {
    class Dialog;
}
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();
private slots:
    void onLineEdit();
    void onButtonClicked();
private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this, SLOT(onLineEdit()));
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onButtonClicked()));
}
Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
void Dialog::onLineEdit() {
    qDebug() << QString("line edit finish");
}
void Dialog::onButtonClicked() {
    qDebug() << QString("button clicked");
}
```

Above is the demo code, the functionality is very simple, and the interface is as the picture shows.
[The GUI interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx1Oo.png)

In this pic, a groupBox wraps the lineEdit & pushButton. When I input some text into the LineEdit, then move the mouse to another place, but within the groupBox, the LineEdit Won't emit the editingfinished() signal.

This situation means the lineEdit doesn't lose focus. This problem is really strange. Could you tell me what's wrong.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Do you simply move the mouse or you click somewhere else?

Answer (score -1):

Though the [documentation of `QLineEdit::editingFinished()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) doesn't state it explicitely, *focus* means in this case [*keyboard focus*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/focus.html), e. g. pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key or <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but not moving the mouse cursor someplace else without clicking on some other focusable widget.

If you want to implement a different behaviour and don't know how you should say so.

Comment: I found the key point of the problem, as only LineEdit has the strongFocus, while other widgets around it have no focus, so LineEdit can't lose focus anymore. The solution is to make others widgets also have focus, tab focus, click focus or strong focus. This can work very well.